# Excel: Copy URLs to Name List without using Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

I have two columns, one containing names (A) and other containing URLs (B).
I need the names from A to be hyperlinked to the corresponding URLs from B. I can use the Formula =HYPERLINK(B,A) but, the resulting column has a formula and I can't get rid of the parent (A, B) columns other than hiding them.

Is there another way to do this, or is hiding columns the only way to do it?

Comment: Needless to mention, other than manually copy-pasting the URLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm understanding your question correctly, try using the following steps:

`1` Starting in column c1, use the formula:

```
="x=hyperlink("""&B1&""","""&A1&""")"
```

`2` Fill down for all the links that you need.

`3` Copy the cells in Column C and paste value into Column D.

`4` Then use find/replace to change "x=" to "=".

This should get you the formulas that you want.  Be sure that your urls are in 'http://' format, or excel will not recognize the web address.

Comment: Wow! That was mighty clever!! Hats off sir! My only question is now to format them as hyperlinks. After doing the above, it gives me the hyperlinked cells but not formatted as hyperlinks. I have to manually F2-enter on each to show their "true" colors.

Comment: Just make sure that the cell location is set to general before you do the find/replace.  It should work.  If you're trying to get the color & underline, you could always select the entire range and format it manually, so long as the links work.  Best

Comment: I just formatted them as hyperlinks. Stupid me!
Thank you Amoy!